# Symfony DomCrawler is not outputing anything

Tags: php, guzzle

This is the code I am using

```
$client = new Client();

$requests = [
$client->createRequest('GET', 'http://httpbin.org'),
$client->createRequest('GET', 'http://httpbin.org')
];

$options = [
'complete' => [
    [
        'fn' => function (CompleteEvent $event) {
            $crawler = new Crawler('GET',  $event->getRequest()->getUrl());
            echo '<p>'.$crawler->filter('title')->text().'</p>';
        },
        'priority' => 0,
        'once'     => false
    ]
  ]
];

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests, $options);
$pool->wait();
```

It gives no error but it outputs nothing either. I have tried replacing the URLs but still I get no output.

Comment: is `error_reporting` on for all `errors` and `warnings`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue with the code sample is the instantiation of your `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler` object.  As currently written, "GET" is the sole content of `$crawler`; as a result the call to `$crawler->filter()` returns an instance of `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler` that contains an empty DOMNodeList.  This is why your output is empty.

Replace:

```
$crawler = new Crawler('GET',  $event->getRequest()->getUrl());
```

with:

```
$crawler = new Crawler(null, $event->getRequest()->getUrl());
$crawler->addContent(
    $event->getResponse()->getBody(),
    $event->getResponse()->getHeader('Content-Type')
);
```

Comment: Hey Shaun, I got `Undefined property: GuzzleHttp\Event\CompleteEvent::$getResponse`  this error after changing the code.

Comment: Alright I you mistyped `getResponse()` on first line as `getResponse` Thank you it works now.

Comment: Hey Shaun I wanted to ask jut one more thing are these request asynchronous now?

Comment: My apologies.  There was a typographical error within my example.  I have since corrected it.  Yes your requests are being made asynchronously, so long as the number of requests you are attempting to make is less then the pool size.  More information on pool size can be found within the Guzzle documentation.